# How to force the display of favicon.ico instead of favicon.png?

Tags: html, icons, shortcut, favicon

This is how I have set up the icon-links in my header.

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico" />
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="apple-touch-icon.png">
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="/screen/favicon.png" sizes="192x192">
```

My 16x16 favicon.ico shows a simplified version of my logo, which looks much better than a downscaled version of a larger PNG. For the touch-icons on mobile devices I have created a 192x192 png of my original logo. Since I added that larger PNG to my header, it is not only used (correctly) as a touch-icon, but also replaces the 16x16 favicon.ico. Thus on the browsers the downscaled png-version is display. I dislike it, cause the ico-version looks better.

Is there any way, to force the display of the ico-version of my favicon in browsers?

Comment: Most browsers can fetch the apple-touch-icon when they need a high resolution icon. You could well remove the image/png icon if it is a problem for you.

Comment: Thank you. But when I remove favicon.png (192x192), Android does not display any touch-icon on a weblink, which I added to the homescreen. It does not use the apple-touch-icon instead, which is only used on iPad and iPhone. That png-icon is needed for the Android-homescreen, and then also used instead of the ico-file, with downscaling to 16x16. That is, what I want to block or avoid.

Comment: Sounds legit! I write an answer right away :)

Answer (score 0):

If the reason of your high-resolution image/png icon is Android, then you should declare it via a [web manifest](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Manifest).

This is what [RealFaviconGenerator](https://realfavicongenerator.net/) does: it only declares low-resolution image/png icons in the HTML. So [desktop browsers only pick those, whereas Android get the high resolution icons it expects](https://realfavicongenerator.net/favicon_compatibility). Even if you don't plan to use the service, you can generate a fake set of icons and adapt the generated code and files to your needs.

Full disclosure: I'm the author of this service.